# Find joint expectation value $\mathbb E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2})$

Tags: expectation

> Let the pair (X,Y) be uniformly distributed on the unit disc, so that
>
> $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\pi}&\text{if }x^2+y^2\leq1,\\0&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$
>
> Find $\mathbb E\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ and $\mathbb E(X^2+Y^2)$.

We are not familiar with coordinate transformations, and my teacher told us to simply look carefully at the volume we're trying to calculate.

We know that

$$\mathbb E(g(X,Y))=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$.

Applying this to $g(X,Y)=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ we get

$\begin{aligned}\mathbb E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2})=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sqrt{x^2+y^2}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\\
=&\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\pi^{-1}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx. \end{aligned}$

Now here I would need to apply some useful transformation. Could someone help me out from here?

Comment: @Helios How can this be an area? It's a volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This
$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\pi^{-1}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
Should be  this
$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\pi^{-1}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
Then change to polar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$, and remember that the jacobian for this transformation is $r$, the integral becomes
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}r^2\pi^{-1}\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, which I think is much more elegant, is to do the transformation at the outset. Instead of picking $X$ and $Y$ you pick $r \sim [0, 1]$ and $\theta \sim [0, 2\pi)$ and do the transformation
$$
\begin{align}
x &= \sqrt r \cos \theta\\
y &= \sqrt r \sin \theta
\end{align}
$$
Then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt r$ and $x^2 + y^2 = r$ so you have
$$
\mathbb E[r] = \frac{1}{2}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb E[\sqrt r] = \frac{2}{3}
$$
Also check out : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html